# How to fill a customized shape?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-path

in the following code I want to fill the area defined by $v_2, v_3, v_5$ with dashed lines. I know how to fill a shape if the line connecting $v2$ and $v3$ is not bend with

```
\draw[fill = gray] (v2)--(v3)--(v5) cycle
```

But what do I do in order to

1. fill up to the bend line
2. get a dashed filling.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path 
(1,2) coordinate (v1) node[below]{$v_1$}
(2,0) coordinate (v2) node[below]{$v_2$}
(3,0) coordinate (v3) node[below]{$v_3$}
(4,4) coordinate (v4) node[above]{$v_4$}
(3,3) coordinate (v5) node[above]{$v_5$};
\draw (v1)--(v2) (v3)--(v4) (v2)--(v5) (v3)--(v5);
    
\draw (v2).. controls +($.1*(v2)-.1*(v1)$) and +($.1*(v3)-.1*(v4)$) .. (v3);  
    
\foreach \p in {v1,v2,v3,v4,v5}
\fill (\p) circle(2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Thank you very much  in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

First, close your path. Then fill it.

If you fill in, say, orange, you get:

[image: orange]

If you want to fill it with what you call a dashed filling, use the `patterns` or the `patterns.meta` libraries:

[image: pattern]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path 
(1,2) coordinate (v1) node[below left]{$v_1$}
(2,0) coordinate (v2) node[below left]{$v_2$}
(3,0) coordinate (v3) node[below right]{$v_3$}
(4,4) coordinate (v4) node[above]{$v_4$}
(3,3) coordinate (v5) node[above]{$v_5$};
\draw (v1)--(v2) (v3)--(v4) (v2)--(v5) (v3)--(v5);
    
%\draw[fill=orange] (v2).. controls +($.1*(v2)-.1*(v1)$) and +($.1*(v3)-.1*(v4)$) .. (v3) -- (v5) -- cycle;  
\draw[pattern=north west lines, pattern color=blue] (v2).. controls +($.1*(v2)-.1*(v1)$) and +($.1*(v3)-.1*(v4)$) .. (v3) -- (v5) -- cycle;  
    
\foreach \p in {v1,v2,v3,v4,v5}
\fill (\p) circle(2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for